# Looping JSON Map in PHP

Tags: php, json, loops

I am new to PHP and basically I am trying to loop that `mapToLoop` map but I don't really know how to, I tried `foreach($json->mapToLoop as $entry)` but it doesn't seem to work.

My json:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "mapToLoop": {
    "1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": {
        "name": "StackOverflow"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
$json = json_decode($jsonStr);
foreach ($json->mapToLoop as $key => $value) { //Line 35
    echo "$key:$value";
}
```

That error occurs: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in test.php:35`

**SOLUTION:** Using `json_decode($jsonStr, true);` fixes it

Comment: You need to [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json first, then loop over the results. Btw "_it doesn't seem to work_" is not a very helpful error description

Comment: @brombeer I do that already

Comment: Not apparent from the little code you posted, maybe post all of the relevant code and what it doesn't do that you want it to

Comment: Okay, to be clear; I get that error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array... and my loop is: foreach ($json->mapToLoop as $entry)

Comment: Thus it returned a php object [Setting and Getting Properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post all relevant code and any errors you might get or what doesn't work as you expect it to so it is all in _one_ place and people don't have to wade through the comments to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Edited, sorry for not being clear

Comment: I would use `json_decode($jsonStr, true); foreach ($json['mapToLoop'] as $key => $value) { ...` but then you will need another level of nesting to access the `key*` values

Comment: Thank you @Nick, that worked perfectly, but just curious and want to learn, what would I do if I didn't use that "true" parameter?

Comment: @EyüpYıldız the `true` parameter makes `json_decode` return an associative array instead of an object, so you can then iterate over key/value pairs (which you can't do with an object)

Comment: @EyüpYıldız if you didn't use `true`, you would need to iterate over the properties using [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars) for example https://3v4l.org/8SCEA - note you would need to then iterate over the first value's properties as well